# Broken for loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, slideshow

I have a for loop that dictates what shows in my slideshow though it doesn't show the new pictures once the the old picture has been dismissed. Here is my for loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if ($('.slideshow a:last-child').css('display') != 'none') {
        $('.slideshow a:last-child').fadeOut(d);
    } else {
        $('.slideshow a:nth-child(' + i + ')').delay(g).fadeOut(d).delay(200).next().fadeIn(d);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/LQSgV/4/

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Because it executes all the slides at ones in that for loop. Not after each other.

Comment: I expect it to go through all the elements one at a time and execute a command each time

Comment: That is not happening with a for loop. You need to do it in another way. You can add a callback function to your `fadeIn` function to trigger your next slide. Just make a function out of it or something.

Comment: Please can you give an example